# Printing a Client Report (rdlc): Is it possible to combine landscape and portrait pages?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, orientation, reportviewer, rdlc

We are using a ReportViewer to show Client Reports (rdlc) to the user. The user can then print the report using the built-in ReportViewer functionality.

We are able to design either landscape or portrait reports.

But is it also possible to mix these two, i.e. use landscape and portrait in one report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Maybe you can create two reports, one landscape and the other one portrait?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. You can only set `PageHeight` and `PageWidth` in [Report Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee663021%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so these properties are applied to entire report.